# Are questions about how to use WebGL2 on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I am new to the site, but not to the SE network. The reason that I signed up for Game Development is that I have a bunch of questions related to WebGL2, and how it can be used for 2D rendering for games, that I would like to ask over a period of time.

I have asked [my first question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/202692/efficiently-pass-one-uniform-value-per-polygon-or-quad-to-the-fragment-shader-in), and recieved a very nice answer. So  far, so good. Before I continue asking, I would just like to check that this is actually a desired topic here? Or would it be better to ask over att Stack Overflow? I don't want to be spamming something that is borderline off topic.

Here are some examples of future questions I might want to ask:

- How do I work around the fact that the fragment shader can not read from the framebuffer I am rednering to?
- Should I reuse the same vertex buffer for multiple draw calls (empty and refill each time), or is that bad?
- How can I efficiently combine batch rendering of quads with z-ordering?

I figure this would fall under "game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc)"?

Comment: For the "read from frame buffer" one, make sure to describe at least one specific visual effect you're trying to achieve by doing that. Then we can show ways to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for asking!

Yes, this all seems on-topic here!